# Changing background images with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and HTML and I can't seem to figure out want is wrong. This is part of an assignment I have for class so the structure/code is formatted the same way as an example the professor provided.

I'm trying to rotate between different background images.

This is what I have for the script:

```
   var bakground = [];
    background[0] = new Image();
    background[0].src = "Images/blue.jpg";
    background[1] = new Image();
    background[1].src = "Images/chalkboard_web.jpg";
    background[2] = new Image();
    background[2].src = "Images/computer-scince-education.jpg";
    background[3] = new Image();
    background[3].src = "Images/universidad.jpg";

    var i = 0;
    var temp = new Image();
    function wallpaper()
    {
        temp = background[i].src;
        i++;
        if(i == background.length)
            i = 0;

        document.body.background = 'temp';
        return false;
    }
```

This is where I'm calling the function:

```
<P/> <b> test changing document body background:</b>

<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button2" value="set background to an image"
   onClick="wallpaper()" >
</P>
```

Comment: `document.body.background = 'temp';` seems wrong. you are setting background to a string, and not the temp image. try `document.body.background = temp;`

Comment: Hello there, welcome to Stack Overflow! When you set `"temp"` to the `background` attribute, you should see an entry in the network tab as `/temp:1 GET https://example.com/temp 404`. Can you see this in your dev tools?

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the "temp" variable you defined above but a string instead!

```js
    function wallpaper()
    {
        temp = background[i].src;
        i++;
        if(i == background.length)
            i = 0;

        document.body.background = temp;
        return false;
    }
```

Should work

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help! you were right about not using the 'temp' variable correctly but even after the change it still isn't working

Comment: because you have a typo, see my answer. background is misspelled. Also, always look into the developer console of your browser

Answer (score 2):

There are several things.

Bugs:

- type in background
- you are setting document.body.background to the string `'temp'` and not to your image.
- you are using a closing p-tag to open the paragraph. Should be `<p>` instead of `</P>`

Other improvements:

- you don't even need to create `new Image()`, the string of where to get the image should suffice.
- you don't need to have `temp` as a global variable.
- you can more easily modulo the iterator rather then re-setting it to 0
- tags and attributes are case insensitive. It's common to use lowercase, though.
- elements like `input` can / should have closing tags or be self-closing.
  See example here:

```html
   <html>
        <head>
        <script>
        var background = [
                "https://source.unsplash.com/random",
                "Images/wall.jpg",
                "Images/1road.jpg"
            ];
        var i = 0;
        function wallpaper() {
            document.body.background = background[i++];
            i = i % background.length; // will wrap around the length. look up 'modulo' unsure
            return false;
        }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p/>
                <b> test changing document body background:</b>
                <input type="button" name="button2" value="set background to an image"
                    onClick="wallpaper()" />
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i feel stupid for not noticing that typo before!

Comment: Yes, console tells you, that it cannot find background when it tries to access it. Also, if that works for you now, please accept this as the answer. Will help other people in the future.